# how to read multiple children from xml

Tags: java, xml, xpath

in my project we use xpath
to extract values from xml

for example:

```
String AntLid = "/DokxAPI/DokxReply/ReplyBody/Service-Impact-Rep/AntLid/text()";
```

Now the xml got changed like it has max of 13 children to one lid list
some thing like this

```
<LidList>
  <Lid>33333,33333,33333</Lid>
  <Lid></Lid>
  <Lid></Lid>
  <Lid></Lid>
  <Lid></Lid>
  <Lid></Lid>
  <Lid></Lid>
  <Lid></Lid>
  <Lid></Lid>
  <Lid></Lid>
  <Lid></Lid>
  <Lid></Lid>
  <Lid></Lid>
</LidList>
```

previously
it was like this

```
<LID-List>
  <LID>333333333,333333333,333333333,</LID>
</LID-List>
```

so I used to extract

```
String expressionLID =
    "/DokxAPI/DokxReply/ReplyBody/Service-Impact-Rep/Lid-List/Lid/text()";
```

but now..the xml got changed and..as said b4..it can have 13 children..max 13,min 1
sooo  how do i get the values of each sub list `<lid>`

Comment: You wrote *how do i get the values of each sub list (?)*. This is not an XPath question but a DOM method question in specific host language

Answer (score 4):

First, make sure the element names in your XPath match the case of the actual elements in your input, e.g. `LID`.

Other than that, your XPath expression

```
"/DokxAPI/DokxReply/ReplyBody/Service-Impact-Rep/Lid-List/Lid/text()"
```

already selects all `<LID>` children of `<LID-List>`. It's just a matter of iterating through them in your Java code. If you're having trouble with that part, please show your java code.